# How to set app icon in pixel sense (surface table)?

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

I am writing application for pixel sense which is called "surface table" before. Now I find a problem that the table cannot change the default app icon to my custom icon.

What is the method of changing apps icon?

Answer (score 1):

The icon is set in the application's [XML Registration File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727761.aspx#bkmk_XMLRegistrationFile):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ss:ApplicationInfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xmlns:ss="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Surface/2007/ApplicationMetadata">
    <Application>
        <Title>...</Title>
        <Description>...</Description>
        <ExecutableFile>...</ExecutableFile>
        <Arguments></Arguments>

        <!-- here -->
        <IconImageFile>Resources\ApplicationIcon.png</IconImageFile>

        <Tags></Tags>
   </Application>
</ss:ApplicationInfo>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the icon (the one showed in windows in the windows task bar) in Project > Properties > Application > Resources > Icon and manifest.

The Surface icon can be changed only in the XML Registration file as mentioned by Clemens.